# How do you import a ndjson file in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, libraries, ndjson

I have tried the code below but it's not working

```
import json
with open("/Users/elton/20210228test2.ndjson") as f:
    test2data = ndjson.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. `import ndjson` instead of `import json`. See more here: https://pypi.org/project/ndjson/

```
import ndjson

# load from file-like objects
with open('data.ndjson') as f:
    data = ndjson.load(f)
```

Comment: I tried that and i'm getting this error, is there something i'm doing wrong?

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ndjson'

Comment: did you install ndjson?